# Any size limit for a Joomla extension pack?

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions

Is there any byte size limit a Joomla extension package (compressed .zip) file?  Assume we have enough PHP maximum upload limit set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, Joomla doesn't set a limit

You only have to take into consideration PHP's:

- max upload size
- max post size
- max execution time